# Bad scrolling in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I have a LLS which shows 2 groups of friends (online and offline). My problem: when i start scrolling LLS - it has 2 variants: 1) LLS scrolling good, 2) it doesnt scrolls. When it doesnt scrolls - I start to verticaly scrolling screen in different places, and in some place of the screen I find the position, where LLS starts scrolling. But! In the second time - in this place LLS doesn't scrolls, and I again try to find the place on screen where LLS scrolling. It looks like LLS's scrollviewer randomly change position and size. Here is my LLS:

```
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="1">
            <Grid Height="500" >
                <toolkit:LongListSelector Name="AllFriendsList" Height="500" Width="420" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource citiesItemTemplate}"
                ListHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource citiesListHeader}" 
                ListFooterTemplate="{StaticResource citiesListFooter}"
                GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource groupHeaderTemplate}"
                GroupItemTemplate="{StaticResource groupItemTemplate}" >
                    <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>

                </toolkit:LongListSelector>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

and styles:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="citiesListHeader">
        <Border Background="Purple">
            <TextBlock Text="Cities Header" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="citiesListFooter">
        <Border Background="Green">
            <TextBlock Text="Cities Footer" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- The template for city items -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="citiesItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Line Style="{StaticResource Line1}" ></Line>
            <Line Style="{StaticResource Line2}" ></Line>
            <TextBlock Margin="75,15,40,0" FontSize="30" Name="Name" Text="{Binding Name}" Tap="GetUserInfo" />
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Name="Photo" >
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Image}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation" />
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>


    <!-- The group header template, for groups in the main list -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="groupHeaderTemplate">
        <Border Background="YellowGreen" Margin="6">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="groupItemTemplate" >
        <Border Background="YellowGreen" Width="99" Height="99" Margin="6">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I didnt change controls names, I tooked them from [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios) .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in that scroll works only on the controls. So if I put mouse on image or textblock - it scrolls fine (my LLS has empty places with out any controls), and when I try to scroll on empty place - it doesn't scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

Put a transparent background on the StackPanel in your DataTemplate. The hit testing system has to have pixels to work with, even if they are transparent. Don't go crazy adding backgrounds everywhere, however, or your frame rate will drop.